# Error 1064 mysql - mariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo un problema al querer generar un nueva tabla en la db.

Al ejecutar la query me devuelve un error 1064, el problema es que no se donde esta el error de mi query o porque me devolverá dicho error.

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para generar la tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE lineas_pedidos(

id                  INT(255) auto_increment not null,
pedido_id           INT(255) not null,
producto_id         INT(255) not null,

CONSTRAINT pk_linea_pedidos PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT FK1_PEDIDOS FOREING KEY(pedido_id) REFERENCES pedidos(id),
CONSTRAINT FK2_PRODUCTOS FOREING KEY(producto_id) REFERENCES productos(id)


)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Cuando ejecuto dicha query, directamente mysql/mariaDB me devuelve el error 1064

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREING KEY(pedido_id) REFERENCES pedidos(id),
>       CONSTRAINT FK2_PRODUCTOS FORE' at line 8

Comment: Se escribe `FOREIGN KEY`, lo tienes mal escrito

Comment: Sabes que tenes razón, gracias! :)